# Cannot pass data to child component with Context React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I am storing some data in my parent component to an array of objects.
After that I am storing it in Context in order to pass it to another component.
So my parent looks like this:

```
    export type HistoryData = {
          input: string;
          date: string;
        };
        
        type Props = {
          children?: ReactNode;
        };
        
        type ContextProviderType = {
          history: HistoryData[];
          setHistory: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<HistoryData[]>>;
        };
        
        const values = {} as HistoryData;
        
        export const Context = createContext<ContextProviderType>({
          history: [],
          setHistory: () => {},
        });
        
        export const Overview = ({ children }: Props) => {
          const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');
          const [data, setData] = useState<any[]>([]);
          const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
          const [history, setHistory] = useState<HistoryData[]>([]);
        
          const handleSubmit = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            setLoading(false);
            axios
              .get(`https://api.github.com/users/${inputText}/repos`)
              .then((response) => {
                setData(response.data);
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.log('error', error);
                setLoading(true);
              });
            const clonedValues = { ...values };
            clonedValues.input = inputText;
            clonedValues.date = new Date().toLocaleString();
            setHistory([...history, clonedValues]);
          };
          console.log(history);
      <Context.Provider value={{ history, setHistory }}>
    ....
</Context.Provider>
     );
    };
    
    export const useContextData = () => useContext(Context);
```

So basically, after each input i am storing the input and the exact date of the input while it clicked, and later i want to pass it to the other component like that:

```
import { useContextData } from './Overview';

    const History = () => {
      const { history, setHistory } = useContextData();
      console.log(history);
```

but all I get is an empty `history` array [].

Just to clarify, the `History` component is another page with `/history` url...
I am not sure maybe that re-renders and clears the array??

My App.tsx:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Overview />} />
        <Route path="/history" element={<History />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And my index.tsx:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: The History component needs to be a descendant of Context.Provider. It seems it is returning the default value, so most likely that's the issue.

Comment: The History component is actually another page. Maybe that is the issue?

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. You need to have one Context.Provider as a parent of both the Overview and History pages.

Comment: It basically has to be another page, so I guess storing data with Context is not the best way if I want to change the URL path? Should I use `localStorage` maybe?

Comment: Are you using FE routing? You can always have your provider somewhere near the root component in that case. Or do you reload the whole page, so no SPA?

Comment: In case you are reloading all JS, you can use localStorage or sessionStorage, depending on whether you need it to be consistent across tabs or the same in every tab.

Comment: I updated my question, you can check the routing. I'm not sure what `FE routing` is? @AsenMitrev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to share a context, two components must be descendents of the same Provider. That means that you need to have the context provider as a parent to your components.

Export `Context` and `useContextData` into another file.

In your `App.tsx` file you will need to wrap the routes in the context provider:

```
function App() {
  const [history, setHistory] = useState<HistoryData[]>([]);
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ history, setHistory }}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Overview />} />
        <Route path="/history" element={<History />} />
      </Routes>
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}
```

Then in each of the files you would access the `history` and `setHistory` props using context:

```
   const History = () => {
      const { history, setHistory } = useContextData();
```

```
   export const Overview = ({ children }: Props) => {
      const { history, setHistory } = useContextData();
```

This should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using
`useContext`
hook inside the
`History`
component. But you have created the
`context`
inside the
`Overview`
component. You must pass the values to
`Overview`
component in order to use it in
`History`
component.

```
const [history, setHistory] = useState&lt;HistoryData[]&gt;([]);

        return (
            &lt;Context.Provider value={{ history, setHistory }}&gt;
            ...
            &lt;/Context.Provider&gt;
        )
```